# Intellij IDEA 14: Error Loading Project: Cannot load module cars-service

Tags: intellij-idea

With my last restart of my mac I had a problem with IntelliJ IDEA project : the .iml file was deleted and I have

> Error loading project: cannot load module cars-service Details ....

in the console.

Besides that, the structure view of the project has disapeared.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Finally, I imported my project via import project so the iml file was recreated.

Comment: Thanks for a solution. I didn't think it was too simple and had tried to add modules again, that was too difficult. Finally found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391581/automatically-migrating-projects-to-gradle-in-android-studio and imported an existing Android Studio project again. That's a nonsence, but it works. After that saw your solution.

Answer (score 30):

Closing intelliJ. Deleting the .idea folder and re-opening intellij worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a billion. I was trying to fix my project after accidentally deleting  myProject.iml for 2 hours!!!  Your answered helped.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: super perfect solution

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me this morning*, and fortunately there's a fairly straightforward solution.

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` (or go to `File > Project Structure...`) and click `Modules` on the left of the window.
2. Click the green `+` above the list of modules then `New Module`. Select the type of module (Java, Android, Flash, what have you) and click `Next`.
3. Enter the details of the lost module. Click the browse button to the right of Content Root and navigate to the directory that contains your lost module. The module name will be populated with the directory name by default, but you can rename it without issue.

(*I... got a bit gung-ho with the old `git clean -fd`. I don't recommend it.)

Answer (score 10):

> The error has nothing to do with gems. Please try deleting the .idea directory and using "Open Directory" on the same directory again to recreate it.-- Dmitry Jemerov

[↑an answer on intellij-support.jetbrains.com](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206714275--Cannot-load-module-file-RM4-5)

This helped me. I just closed Pycharm, then delete .idea directory , then I open Pycharm again, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 8):

Please try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue with PHPStorm (which is also idea based), caused by a renaming of my project. Solution was simple: I just needed to remove the corresponding line for the module declaration in file `<project-directory>/.idea/modules.xml`. Re-opening the project was not needed as it seemed to me, but I did it anyway.

Have had this issue with PHPStorm 2017.1.3.

Comment: This is the right answer if you deleted the module folder and don´t need it anymore.

Comment: .idea/workspace.xml can also contain a reference to the module.

Answer (score 3):

IML file is necessary to load the project.

Locate the folder the .iml file used to be in > right click > Local history > show history.From there you should be able to restore that iml file

Comment: Actually, when i do that it doesn't show the iml file in the local history :S

Answer (score 1):

you can fix it by select your pom file. right click and then reimport