# Automatically Migrating projects to gradle in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I made some apps in the past with android studio, and there was no problems with them. 
And I could open example projects from many sites, for example:  developer.android.com/.
Now after an update of android studio, I can't open projects in android studio without migrating them manually, which was done before the update by android studio itself.
What could be the problem now?
First I get this warning, that android framework is detected.
[image]
Then after choosing the setup frameworks and clicking ok, I get this:
[image]

As you can see it is not gradle based project.
What can I do to make android studio automatically migrate projects again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**IMPORTING ANDROID STUDIO PROJECT IN ANDROID STUDIO:**

If you want to import An Android Studio Project then do the following:

**1.**
**Select** *Open an existing Android Studio Project*

[image]

**2.** **Browse** your desired project derectory.

**3.** Now rather than selecting the folder that contains your project, you have to select the `build.gradle` file that is just inside of your parent folder of the project.

[image]

It will not create any problem and will not ask you to migrate into `gradle` and import any framework at all.

**IMPORTING ECLIPSE PROJECT IN ANDROID STUDIO:**

If you want to import Eclipse Project in Android Studio:

**1.** **Select** *Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)*

**2.** Then nothing special just follow the instructions in the wizard.

Comment: thanks. the problem was, that after updateing android studio i didn't find the option import project, which was moved to be a subcategory of "New.." in the updated version of android studio. i do open alle projects, even those which dont have the gradle structure, thats caused the error.