# What action should be taken when if modules cannot be loaded

Tags: git, android-studio

```
Android Studio 2.3.1
git version 2.9.3
```

I have been working on my android project from 2 different computers. I use git as my version control.

I got this message when I was opening my android project on another computer. I wasn't sure what I should do?

Here is the message dialog

[image]

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio required this information to when loading the project.

See the questions below on how to recover those project files.

- [Error loading project in Android Studio: cannot load modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705698/error-loading-project-in-android-studio-cannot-load-modules)
- [Intellij IDEA 14: Error Loading Project: Cannot load module cars-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986396/intellij-idea-14-error-loading-project-cannot-load-module-cars-service)

One of the reason for the above can be that someone accidentally changed them or delete them and pushed the change.

Issue

```
git log -p <path>/BusbyMovies.iml
```

Maybe this will give you a clue on what happened.

I recommend adding .iml to git ignore as they may contain machine specific information that will interrupt other user that share the same repository.
To your .gitignore file in the root of the project add the following.

```
# Intellij
.idea/
*.iml
*.iws
```

If you do not have a .gitignore file just create one using any text editor.
Commit and push as usual

Update: I use the above un my.gitignore which works for me.
Jetbrains has some additional details in case you do want to [share a project files with other developers.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a quick on should everything in the .idea directory should be ignored? I have the following: compiler.xml  copyright  encodings.xml  gradle.xml  libraries  misc.xml  modules.xml  runConfigurations.xml  vcs.xml  workspace.xml